# Retrieving an ActiveRecord length validation returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to retrieve the maxmimum lenght validation of a ActiveRecord field in one of my views.

The following works fine in rails console and returns the correct value :

```
irb(main):046:0> micropost = Micropost.new
=> #<Micropost id: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):047:0> micropost._validators[:content][1].options[:maximum].to_s
=> "140"
```

However, when I use the same code in my controller it returns nil :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?      
      @micropost = Micropost.new
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
      @content_max = @micropost._validators[:content][1].options[:maximum].to_s
    end
  end

...

end
```

I also tried to include a method in my ApplicationHelper, which also returns nil ;-(

```
def content_max
  Micropost._validators[:content][1].options[:maximum].to_s
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_validators` array might not be in the same order whether you're in the console or in a web request.

```
Micropost._validators[:content].find {|v| v.class == ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator} .options[:maximum].to_s
```

should do what you want.

IMHO, a better solution would be to store the length in a constant (I somehow doubt the `_validators` array is part of the official API) :

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 140

    validates :content, :length => {:maximum => MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH}

    # Rest of the code...
end
```

and get the length with :

```
Micropost::MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH
```

Comment: Hi Benoit, 

I tried your first solution and it worked fine, except when submitting the page with too many characters in the input field, the @variable I assigned the _validators value to, turned out to be nil for some reason. Maybe this variable is outside the scope of the shared/_error_messages partial?

Anyway, because of this and your concern about the _validators array being part of the official API, I decided to implement your second solution (which I also find much cleaner) and added a helper method to get the length in my views.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You're welcome. Ruby is awesome because it lets you muck with the internals of the libraries you're using, but it sometimes can hurt you (not that I haven't been guilty of doing it ;-) ).